# running sage 300 ERP macro without triggering a login?

Tags: sage-erp

I use sage 300 erp heavily and am setting up some macros, the main issue is that they prompt me to sign in each time. If I want to run a task in the background each day on a schedule to print out a report to a directory, it requires me to babysit it. Is it possible to run my sage 300 erp macros without logging in or leaving sage 300 erp logged in?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run Sage macro without logging into Sage.  You can setup a task scheduler to run the macro available here:

http://www.greytrix.com/blogs/sageaccpacerp/2013/05/15/run-vba-macro-without-logging-to-sage-300-erp/

You have to call your specific macro(s) from it.  I'm trying to do the same setup myself.

Comment: this looks promising! let me know once you get it working!